# pop of a view from a button callback

Tags: wpf

I have Button with a callback where I'm instaitating another view and then I want to pop it up. Is there something like View.show() that I can use? Or View.Visible = true;

I dont' want to use Popup in xaml if I don't have to(not sure how that works but I've seen it)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something like View.show() that I can use? Or View.Visible = true;

No. So either use popups or some shell window which does nothing more than host the view.

Comment: Please see CodeNaked's and my comment on your question.